# How to show differences in a commit message that was modified with "git rebase -i"?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-rebase, git-diff

I did a `git rebase -i` and reworded a commit.

How do I show the diff between the new commit message that I committed and the old commit message?  (e.g., from the commit in `git reflog`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need first to find the relevant commit hashes, using [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).
For instance:

```bash
git reflog

a123b4c (HEAD -> main) HEAD@{0}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/main
a123b4c (HEAD -> main) HEAD@{1}: rebase -i (pick): commit message 1
c456d7e HEAD@{2}: rebase -i (start): checkout HEAD~2
e890f1g HEAD@{3}: commit: old commit message 2
```

In this example:

- `a123b4c` is the hash of the new commit (the one with the reworded message), and
- `e890f1g` is the hash of the original commit (the one with the old message).

Now, you can display the commit messages by using the [`git show --pretty=format:%s <commit-hash>` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#Documentation/git-show.txt---prettyltformatgt), replacing `<commit-hash>` with the hashes you found in the previous step:

```bash
git show --pretty=format:%s a123b4c
commit message 1

git show --pretty=format:%s e890f1g
old commit message 2
```

That will give you the commit messages for the respective hashes, which you can then compare manually.

---

You can write a bash function that compares two commit messages using the `diff` command.
That function takes two arguments: the hashes of the two commits you want to compare.

```bash
diff_git_commit_messages() {
    if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
        echo "Usage: ${FUNCNAME[0]} <commit-hash-1> <commit-hash-2>"
        return
    fi
    diff \
        <(git show --pretty=format:%s $1) \
        <(git show --pretty=format:%s $2)
}
```

e.g.,

```bash
$ diff_git_commit_messages 6bfa911 HEAD
1c1
< add file
---
> my new msg
```

Comment: Thanks @VonC!  I was hoping for a single command that also did the diff, but this will do.  I can create a shell function now to get it into a single command.

Comment: @RobBednark I understand. I have edited the answer to include such a script.

Comment: Thanks @VonC!  I changed your script to a function, and simplified it by using process substitution (eliminating the need for managing temp files).

Comment: @RobBednark Thank you for the edit, that looks much better!

Answer (score 0):

You say that you only reworded a commit. In that case you can use
`git-range-diff(1)`. This command will show you all the changes, but I
suppose since there aren't any changes to the data (files) then the small
context diffs for that won't be too distracting.

You need some base commit that both have in common. If you have a feature
branch that you have rebased then you can use the branch that you branched
off of. Let's just say `main`.

Then you first need the old version. I have tagged that `first` in this
case for convenience.

Finally you need your current version. If this is `HEAD` then you can use
`@` or `HEAD`.

First I wrote this commit message:

```
Short message
```

Then I reworded it to this:

```
Short message

Actually let's write a longer message.
```

The result:

```
$ git range-diff @~ first second
1:  69a2ff6 ! 1:  23825c2 Short message
    @@ Metadata
      ## Commit message ##
         Short message

    +    Actually let's write a longer message.
    +
      ## a (new) ##
     @@
     +hello
```

The coloring (lost here) will make a distinction between the pluses on the
metadata and the plus on the data (`hello`): the added lines in the
metadata section are added between the “versions”, while the `hello` is
added by both versions (so no interdiff).

Well. I suppose a supplementary screenshot won't hurt:

[image: interdiff]